# Disable last page on ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

i'm using viewpagerIndicator in my app, i have 200 pages. is possible disable the Swipe 1 page before the last page?

Example my currentpage is the 199 here the swipe is disble and never change to the next page, only the previous pages.

**EDIT**: i have one calendar in the Tabindicator, the pages show info for day, i need show the next day but not swipe because not exist info for this reason i need disable this page.

Exam:

19/ago/2014 | 20/ago/2014 | 21/ago/2014

before      |Current      |Last Page

in before i can swipe left and right but in Current i need only swipe left and disable right is possible?

Comment: Get rid of the 200th page.

Answer (score 0):

You can return 199 from getCount() from adapter that way viewpager will not know there are 200 pages.

EDIT:

Well In that case, you have to override viewpager and manually disable the motion when viewpager is showing second last page.
It would look something like this
First extend : class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {...}

```
float lastX;
@Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if(getCurrentItem() == getAdapter().getCount()-1){
       if(ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        lastX = ev.getX();
        // Just touch down let viewpager also handle touch event
       return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
       }
       else if(ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
          float xDiff = ev.getX() - lastX;
          if(xDiff > 0){
               // Attempt to move right on second last page
               // Return false, we dont want to handle this movement
               return false;
          }
          else{
              // Left you can move
              return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event); 
          }
       }
       // Notice that we are not updating lastX on motion towards left 
       // This is to enable user can swipe towards left a bit and comeback, but dont dare go right
    }
    else{
      // Not on second last page let viewpager handle page event
      return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```